# WSL - Substrate Node Template Compilation Error

Tags: substrate-node-template, wsl

GM, I installed the dependencies for WSL mentioned in the docs, but I am unable to compile the template node. Any tips?

```
zach@DESKTOP-P2G1H4R:~/substrate/substrate-node-template$ cargo build --package node-template --release
   Compiling wasm-opt-sys v0.111.0
   Compiling librocksdb-sys v0.8.3+7.4.4
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
warning: compilation terminated.

error: failed to run custom build command for `wasm-opt-sys v0.111.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-9ea94ca4aad9a4e6/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXX
  HOST_CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXXFLAGS
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS
  CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_PREFIX=wasm-opt-sys
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_LINKS=binaryen
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR0=/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-89f52395fdb4b223/out/cxxbridge/include
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR1=/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-89f52395fdb4b223/out/cxxbridge/crate
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR2=/home/zach/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/wasm-opt-sys-0.111.0/binaryen/src
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR3=/home/zach/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/wasm-opt-sys-0.111.0/binaryen/src/tools
  cargo:CXXBRIDGE_DIR4=/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-89f52395fdb4b223/out
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXX
  HOST_CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXXFLAGS
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS
  CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  running: "c++" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-89f52395fdb4b223/out/cxxbridge/include" "-I" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-89f52395fdb4b223/out/cxxbridge/crate" "-I" "/home/zach/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/wasm-opt-sys-0.111.0/binaryen/src" "-I" "/home/zach/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/wasm-opt-sys-0.111.0/binaryen/src/tools" "-I" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-89f52395fdb4b223/out" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-DTHROW_ON_FATAL" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/wasm-opt-sys-89f52395fdb4b223/out/1b6f66997aeb10ce-parsing.o" "-c" "/home/zach/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/wasm-opt-sys-0.111.0/binaryen/src/wasm/parsing.cpp"
  
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
warning: compilation terminated.
warning: c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
warning: compilation terminated.
warning: c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
warning: compilation terminated.

error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v0.8.3+7.4.4`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-3172205394e5ba33/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=rocksdb/
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXX
  HOST_CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXXFLAGS
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS
  CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXX
  HOST_CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXXFLAGS
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS
  CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXX
  HOST_CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXX
  CXX = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CXXFLAGS
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CXXFLAGS
  CXXFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/cache/cache_entry_roles.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/cache_entry_roles.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/cache/cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/cache.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/cache/cache_key.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/cache_key.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/cache/cache_reservation_manager.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/cache_reservation_manager.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/cache/clock_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/clock_cache.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/cache/fast_lru_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/fast_lru_cache.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/cache/lru_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/lru_cache.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/cache/compressed_secondary_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/compressed_secondary_cache.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/cache/sharded_cache.o" "-c" "rocksdb/cache/sharded_cache.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/arena_wrapped_db_iter.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/arena_wrapped_db_iter.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_fetcher.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_fetcher.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_addition.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_addition.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_builder.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_builder.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_garbage.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_garbage.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_meta.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_meta.cc"
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_reader.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_file_reader.cc"
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_garbage_meter.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_garbage_meter.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_format.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_format.cc"
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_sequential_reader.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_sequential_reader.cc"
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_writer.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_log_writer.cc"
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/blob/blob_source.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/blob/blob_source.cc"
  exit status: 0

  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/db_impl/compacted_db_impl.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/db_impl/compacted_db_impl.cc"
  exit status: 0
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl.cc"
  exit status: 0

...
  running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/experimental.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/experimental.cc"
  exit status: 0
  cargo:warning=c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
  cargo:warning=compilation terminated.
  exit status: 1
  cargo:warning=c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
  cargo:warning=compilation terminated.
  exit status: 1
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++17" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wshadow" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-Wno-unused-variable" "-Woverloaded-virtual" "-Wnon-virtual-dtor" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-Wno-strict-aliasing" "-Wno-invalid-offsetof" "-msse2" "-std=c++17" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DOS_LINUX" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX" "-DROCKSDB_SUPPORT_THREAD_LOCAL" "-DWITH_JEMALLOC=ON" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-DHAVE_UINT128_EXTENSION=1" "-o" "/home/zach/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-f6edf3e5ee3dd7ff/out/rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_experimental.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/db_impl/db_impl_experimental.cc" with args "c++" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1).
```

Answer (score 2):

Increase your swap space or give more memory to the WSL.

WSL will use half of your physical memory by default.

Also, check:

https://superuser.com/questions/1707758/wsl-2-does-not-have-all-memory-available-to-it

---

Just a tip:

When I run `cargo test --workspace --all-features` under the substrate repo. It took around 100g ram on my computer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip! I'm still getting the same error unfortunately -- I doubled the ram consumption to 16GB. At this point I either need a new computer / upgrade this machine or there is some issue with the C++ dependencies

Comment: Try increasing the swap. And what's your build command?